# WordPress - Get HTML output

Tags: html, wordpress, output

I use WordPress.

**Get HTML output**

Can I get the HTML output from a post or a page? I've read about using `ob_get_contents` but it might be better if I could run it through a hook.

**Title tag**

In my case I want to get the title tag and some other meta data from the HTML output inside wp-admin. I thought of fetching it by using `cURL` but that might slow down the workflow.

**Question**

What is the "correct" solution to this problem?

Comment: Does the post/page you are trying to read its from the same wordpress install? 

If that's the case, you should be able to find the contents of the post or page using native wordpress functions.

Depending on how are you defining the permalinks, you should be able to search for an ID or [slug](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Get_a_post_by_its_slug)

Comment: Yes its the same install. I have the post id and I can get the content but not the whole page html.

Answer (score 2):

Use the built-in HTTP API: http://codex.wordpress.org/HTTP_API

Example:

```
$the_body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( wp_remote_get( get_permalink( 5 ) ) );
```

`$the_body` will contain the actual page content returned by the server.

Comment: I've read about it. Almost like using cURL. If I don't find anything else I might use it.